# zoom to feature selected in dropdown box on map

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I have published wfs layer then populate the dropdown box by wfs layer attribute now I want when user click on the value of dropdown box it will zoom to the feature of wfs layer on the map

so far i have done this,

```
function loadFeatures(json) {
    features = new ol.format.GeoJSON().readFeatures(json, {
        dataProjection: 'EPSG:4326',
        featureProjection: projection
    });

    sourceWFS.addFeatures(features);
    var i;
    var a;
    att = sourceWFS.getFeatures();
    for (i = 0; i < att.length;i++) {
        str[i] = att[i].get("State");
    }

    $.each(str, function(val, text) {
        $('#sel1').append( $('<option></option>').val(val).html(text) )
    });
}

$('#sel1').on('change', function() {
  var b = $('#sel1 :selected').text();
  var extent = att[b].getGeometry().getExtent();
    map.getView().fitExtent(extent,map.getSize());
});
```

but when I select from dropdown it does not zoom to the feature also gives the error,

`Cannot read property 'getGeometry' of undefined`

Comment: can you add the part when you load the options?

Comment: @cabesuon i have edited my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are using the `text` of the option instead of the `value`. In other words you are using a wrong index, `state` property of the feature.

One simple change should fix it,

```
var b = $('#sel1').val();
```

Here you have a full example,

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@master/en/v6.3.1/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
    <style>
      .map {
        height: 400px;
        width: 100%;
      }
      #countries {
        margin-top: .5rem;
        margin-bottom: .5rem;
        height: 2rem;
      }
    </style>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@master/en/v6.3.1/build/ol.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
    <title>Select & Zoom to Country</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <select id="countries"></select>
    <div id="map" class="map"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(function () {
        
        const vector = new ol.layer.Vector({
          source: new ol.source.Vector()
        });

        const map = new ol.Map({
          target: 'map',
          layers: [
            new ol.layer.Tile({
              source: new ol.source.OSM()
            }),
            vector
          ],
          view: new ol.View({
            center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([37.41, 8.82]),
            zoom: 4
          })
        });

        $.getJSON(
          'https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/data/geojson/countries.geojson',
          function (data) {
            loadFeatures(data);
          }
        );

        function loadFeatures(data) {
          // load vector source
          vector.getSource().addFeatures(new ol.format.GeoJSON().readFeatures(data));
          
          const features = vector.getSource().getFeatures();
          // add select options
          $.each(features, function(i, v) {
            $('#countries').append($('<option></option>').val(i).html(v.get('name')));
          });

          $('#countries').on('change', function() {
            const selected = $('#countries').val();
            const extent = vector.getSource().getFeatures()[selected]
              .getGeometry().getExtent();
            map.getView().fit(extent,map.getSize());
          });
        }

      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

When creating the example I realize you have an error when trying to zoom to the feature, the function of the view is `fit`.

Comment: no it does not effect still got an error "[b].getGeometry is not a function"

Comment: show me the value of `b` please .. just a simple `console.log(b)` .. but the way I just realize that there is no need to for `:selected`, check edit

Comment: get the index of first value of dropdown

Comment: var b should get the  index of selected value

Comment: did you use the edit I made, `$( "#myselect" ).val();` should return the selected value ([jquery docs - val()](https://api.jquery.com/val/#val))

Comment: Ok right but got still got an error of get geometry is not a function

Comment: i did this using arcgis js api to zoom to the feature States.selectFeatures(query, FeatureLayer.SELECTION_NEW, function (features) {  
              thePoly = features[0].geometry;  
              theExtent = thePoly.getExtent().expand(2); //Zoom out slightly from the polygon's extent  
              map.setExtent(theExtent);  
            }); now i want to do this using openlayers

Comment: You have an extra error on your code, I realize on creating an example for you, check the update on the answer

Comment: thanks alot when i am doing i got different coordinates it zooms some where else.

Comment: in your code it zoom to the layer portion but actually i want to zoom only to one feature of the layer

Comment: i have tried to create a center then zoom to that coordinates but still same result as yours

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217284/discussion-between-cabesuon-and-sarah-salar).